# how to extract images that are in 2 or more copies in .docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, docx, python-docx

I have a `.docx` with a mix of text and images (some duplicates and some not). I want the script to ultimately return only the images that appear at least twice in the word document (i.e. images that appear once can be discarded).

I've tried using manual extraction using Microsoft word itself and `docx2txt` (shown below) and they extract all images within the word document but it auto-deletes duplicate images (i.e. only one copy of each unique image ends up in the new folder). So in a sense, it's going counter to what I'm eventually aiming to do. Is there any way to solve this or is there a different approach that's better?

```
import docx2txt

text = docx2txt.process(r"C:\Users\name\Documents\document_with_image.docx", r'C:\Users\name\Documents\folder_of_choice')
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the word document to latex and then check for duplicate images from there. You will need to install the library [pypandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/) using the command:-

```
pip install pypandoc
```

`output = pypandoc.convert_file(path, 'latex')`

When converted to latex each image file will be preceded by '\includegraphics'

`tempvar = docx2txt.process(path,impath)`

Now you can scan the directory "impath" where the images have been put to generate a list of the names of the images.

```
image_li={}
for entry in os.scandir(impath):
    if (entry.path.endswith(".png")):
        templ=entry.path.split("\\")
        templ2=templ[-1]
        templ3=templ2.split(".")
        im_name=str(templ3[0])
        image_li[im_name]=0
```

Now you have successfully initialized a dictionary with keys as image names and values as 0.

Now iterate through the latex and whenever you encounter the image name just increment the value by 1.

At the end of parsing the whole latex file, check the image names which have values associated less than 2 and delete them.

```
output_list=output.split('\includegraphics')
for out in output_list:
    for imn in image_li.keys():
        if imn in out:
            image_li[imn]+=1

for entry in os.scandir(impath):
    if (entry.path.endswith(".png")):
        templ=entry.path.split("\\")
        templ2=templ[-1]
        templ3=templ2.split(".")
        im_name=str(templ3[0])
        if image_li[im_name]<=1:
            os.remove(entry)
```

Please mark the answer as approved answer if it helped you :)